# Office.js mail object properties missing in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, office-js

I've got an Outlook web add-in project based on the React and TypeScript scaffolding generated by the Yeoman Office Add-in Generator.  However, the intellisense (I'm using Webstorm) appears to be missing almost all of the properties and methods for the Office.context.mailbox.item object.  e.g. Only body and dateTimeCreated, not even subject and a bunch of others!

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the files generated by Yeoman, or something else (I'm very new to React). Below is a screenshot of the available props, and the index.tsx file that's generated; I'm trying to access a mail item's properties in the Office.initialize function.

[image]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { initializeIcons } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons';

import App from './components/App';

import './styles.less';
import 'office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.min.css';

initializeIcons();

let isOfficeInitialized = false;

const title = 'My Outlook React Add-in';

const render = (Component) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('container')
    );
};

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.initialize = () => {
    isOfficeInitialized = true;
 let item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    emailSubject = item.???
    render(App);
};

/* Initial render showing a progress bar */
render(App);

if ((module as any).hot) {
    (module as any).hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
        const NextApp = require('./components/App').default;
        render(NextApp);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it so happens, I was just discussing with a colleague yesterday, about how to make the d.ts file better for Outlook.

I just sent a pull request to DefinitelyTyped (which also produces the @types/office-js package): https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/26016.
It should be merged soon.

If you want, in the meantime, you can just copy over the resulting d.ts file and use that.  In fact, if your project has `node_modules/@types/office-js` (I assume it does?), you can just temporarily update it manually on your local file system, with the copy from here (from the pull request):  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zlatkovsky/DefinitelyTyped/235072eab26a40527778755dd477cce3bcc494ae/types/office-js/index.d.ts