# More missing TypeScript definitions for Office-JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-js

Similar to the issue I [recently posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518731/office-js-mail-object-properties-missing-in-typescript/50519873#50519873), it seems there are two other omissions (perhaps more):

- Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync: the new options parameter for specifying isRest: true is missing
- Office.context.mailbox.restUrl: also missing

Is there a way I can force the usage of these missing types in my React/TypeScript project (using Webstorm)? I'm geting compiler errors and can't use them at all.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the current [d.ts file in Definitely Typed](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/types/office-js/index.d.ts), it appears both those parameters are listed and described.

Have you updated @types/office-js recently? Several changes, particularly to Outlook, have been checked in recently.

Comment: I swear I looked at that file yesterday and didn't see it, but - it was a long day lol. I had last updated the file on May 25, so I guess I just missed the change - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can always cast something to `any`.  I.e.:
`(Office.context.mailbox as any).restUrl`

I'll let the Outlook Extensibility team know that these two are missing -- but also, if you know exactly what is missing, feel free to just [submit a pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/#make-a-pull-request) on [this file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/office-js/index.d.ts).